# Why is this Go code deadlocking?

Tags: concurrency, go, deadlock, goroutine

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "runtime"
import "time"


func check(id int) {
    fmt.Println("Checked", id)
    <-time.After(time.Duration(id)*time.Millisecond)
    fmt.Println("Woke up", id)
}

func main() {
    defer runtime.Goexit()

    for i := 0; i <= 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println("Called with", i)
        go check(i)
    }

    fmt.Println("Done for")
}
```

I'm very new to Go, so any pointers would be great. How would I go about debugging such a thing?

You can run the snippet http://play.golang.org/p/SCr8TZXQUE

**update**: this works without the line  `<-time.After(time.Duration(id)*time.Millisecond)` on playground, I want to know why? (As mentioned by @dystroy this maybe because of the way playground handles time)

When I try locally, this is the output:

```
Called with  0
Called with  1
Checked 0
Called with  2
Checked 1
Called with  3
Checked 2
Called with  4
Woke up 0
Checked 3
Called with  5
Checked 4
Called with  6
Checked 5
Called with  7
Checked 6
Called with  8
Checked 7
Called with  9
Checked 8
Called with  10
Checked 9
Woke up 1
Done for
Checked 10
Woke up 2
Woke up 3
Woke up 4
Woke up 5
Woke up 6
Woke up 7
Woke up 8
Woke up 9
Woke up 10
throw: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 2 [syscall]:
created by runtime.main
    /tmp/bindist046461602/go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:221

goroutine 5 [timer goroutine (idle)]:
created by addtimer
    /tmp/bindist046461602/go/src/pkg/runtime/ztime_amd64.c:69
exit status 2
```

All the goroutines complete but throws a deadlock anyway. I should note that it doesn't matter if the timer is used, deadlocks either way.

Answer (score 7):

From [the documentation of Goexit](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Goexit) :

> Goexit terminates the goroutine that calls it. No other goroutine is affected. Goexit runs all deferred calls before terminating the goroutine.

You're exiting the main routine. Don't. As you do it, there isn't any routine running after the last one you launched with `go check(i)` has finished, hence the "deadlock". Simply remove this line :

```
defer runtime.Goexit()
```

---

If what you want is to wait in main for a group of goroutines to finish, you may use a [sync.WaitGroup](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func check(id int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    fmt.Println("Checked", id)
    <-time.After(time.Duration(id)*time.Millisecond)
    fmt.Println("Woke up", id)
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i <= 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        fmt.Println("Called with", i)
        go check(i, &wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Done for")
}
```

**EDIT :**

if you're testing it on golang's playground, any `time.After` will deadlock because time is frozen in playground and Goexit maybe exit a routine that doesn't even exist in a standard program.

Comment: With `runtime.Goexit()` I'm waiting for other goroutines to complete, and it seems to work. I mean all the goroutines runs the line `fmt.Println("Woke up")` but it detects a deadlock anyway. Without that line it doesn't wait for other goroutines to finish.

Comment: That's the normal behavior of routines. What are you trying to do ? You want all goroutines to finish before you print "done for" ?

Comment: No I want `main()` to wait for other goroutines to finish.

Comment: This works without the `time.After` line. I want to know why that would cause a deadlock. It should just block, right?

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. I read about `WaitGroup` but I really want to know why the above snippet works without the `<-time.After` line.

Comment: Just a thought (see edit). You're not testing on playground, are you ? There are some differences (time is frozen, more goroutines that what you know, etc.) with a standard go made program.

Answer (score 0):

all your goroutines are waiting for someone to consume the value they are sending in `<-time.After`.
you can just delete the `<-` or make main consume the value of all goroutines you launched.

**Edit**

this worked for me

```
package main

import "fmt"
//import "runtime"
import "time"


func check(id int) {
    fmt.Println("Checked", id)
    <-time.After(time.Duration(id)*time.Millisecond)
    fmt.Println("Woke up", id)
}

func main() {
    //defer runtime.Goexit()

    for i := 0; i <= 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println("Called with", i)
        go check(i)
    }

    fmt.Println("Done for")
}
```

witch is the same solution someone proposed before so I'll propose a solution without a waitgroup

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"


func check(id int, c chan bool) {
    fmt.Println("Checked", id)
    time.After(time.Duration(id)*time.Millisecond)
    fmt.Println("Woke up", id)
    c <- true
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan bool)

    for i := 0; i <= 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println("Called with", i)
        go check(i, c)
    }
    var n uint
    for n<10 {
        <- c
        n++
    }
    fmt.Println("Done for")
}
```

Comment: The value will be discarded and garbage collected AFAIK. As I said it doesn't matter if I keep the line or remove the line, it is still detected as a deadlock.

Comment: You are right. I tested it and turns out you have to not call Goexit or else it won't be garbage collected.